# Code alignment using listings with proportional fonts is poor

Tags: listings

I would like to typeset code using proportional fonts and the `listings` package, but no matter what I do, alignment is always off. Here is an example in Java (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hello_world_program_examples)):

```
\documentclass[10pt,pdftex]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Java, columns=fullflexible, keepspaces}

\begin{lstlisting}
import javax.swing.JFrame;  // Importing class JFrame
import javax.swing.JLabel;  // Importing class JLabel
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();            // Creating frame
        frame.setTitle("Hi!");                  // Setting title frame
        frame.add(new JLabel("Hello, world!")); // Adding text to frame
        frame.pack();                           // Setting size to smallest
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);      // Centering frame
        frame.setVisible(true);                 // Showing frame
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Note that with the monospaced font seen above, all the comments are nicely aligned. I have tried using different combinations of `columns=flexible`, `columns=fullflexible`, `columns=spaceflexible`, and `keepspaces`, but none of them give correct alignment.

Here is what an ideal result should look like:

[image]

Notice that the comments are aligned the same way as in the source code and no spurious spaces have been introduced.

I think this could be done automatically by having a mechanism that detects when alignment is used in the source code. Since I use tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment, this mechanism could be e.g. detection of two or more consecutive spaces.

My LaTeX programming skills are too poor to create this myself, but maybe someone here could give it a go?

Comment: @egreg No, I don't want `columns=fixed`, because this destroys spacing inside words. This option only works if I use monospaced fonts, but as I said, but I would like to use proportional fonts.

Comment: @Manuel If I remove `columns=fullflexible`, it defaults to `columns=fixed`, but this is not what I want. See the reply to egreg.

Comment: `columns=flexible` works for me (with `keepspaces=false`), but you need to add one more space (in this case) before every comment. **EDIT** I don't know how this works, that's the reason I'm just saying what I see. If you need `keepspaces=true` you need to add even more spaces before the comments and that way they align perfectly. How many are needed? No idea :D

Comment: @Manuel Yes, that works in this case, but an automatic solution would be really nice.

Comment: Well, I don't know *how* it works. But it seems that needs a minimum space. May be as a partial solution (until someone explain how it works and how to tune it) you just need to add a little more space by default before the comments (in order to leave enough room to accommodate the alignment).

Comment: @Manuel I just noticed that if I use `columns=flexible` instead of `columns=fullflexible`, the spacing between words tends to be bad. Look at the spacing in the second block of comments. It's very inconsistent.

Comment: True. I've always wondered what was the real feature behind that *weird* spacing/alignment by default in `listings`. I thought I had found some good point, but you proved me wrong. I'm sorry, but, again, I don't know how it works (and even *why* make it work :D, a second try… why not monospaced fonts? Which are lovely :D).

Comment: @Manuel It's just a matter of personal taste. I think if done correctly, code typeset with proportional fonts can look beautiful. Take a look at [this page](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/news/programming-fonts/). I really like the example with Verdana 10.

Comment: @HåkonMarthinsen Another option is to use the [minted](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/) package. I'm not sure, however, how it works with proportional fonts.